# Highcharts set the default y column values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

What am trying to achieve is to have y values of percentage such that it the percentage value of 100 shows high and not starts at 100

example

I have some data

```
data:[100, 100, 100 .....]
```

When i draw a high charts with

```
series: [{
    name: 'Percentage Compliance',
    data: data //the values of percentage
}]
```

Am getting a chart of the following
[image]

What i wanted it to have is have ranges and have the 100% line be at the top not at the bottom.So have a y axis with 0,10,20
,30% ... buit the line to draw at 100%

What else do i need to add.

Answer (score 0):

just include min and max in your chart like

```
yAxis: {
        max: 100,
        min: 0
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your `yAxis`:

```
 yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    tickInterval: 10
 }
```

Comment: am also using a combo multiaxis and am setting yAxis:1 where how di i then set yAxis value of 1